# Use of "the" after the prepostion "of"

Tags: articles, definite-articles

Consider the following sentences:

> 1. We live under the shade of *the* magnetic canopy of *the* Earth.
> 2. We live under the shade of *the* magnetic canopy of Earth.
> 3. We live under the shade of magnetic canopy of *the* Earth.

Which of the above sentences best conforms to the rules of grammar?

Comment: Thank you for asking this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 or 2. The noun phrase "magnetic canopy" needs a 'the' because you are writing about a specific magnetic canopy. There is some disagreement about whether it is better to write 'Earth' or 'the Earth'. [See this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33282/about-definite-article-before-earth-moon-and-sun) for further details.

Comment: Note that the presence of the article is independent of the preposition *of*.